# How do I wrap instances produced by Guice, while not creating them myself but have Guice inject dependencies as needed?

Tags: java, guice

I want to use Guice to produce instances (actually singletons/single instances for the module/dependency injection context), but have some of the managed instances being wrapped in a proxy.

The idea behind this is to add a synchronization layer around a few items which deal with "one at a time" resources. The only solution I've come up with is to create two Injectors.

Given the code below,

```
public class ApplicationContext {
    private Injector injector;
    public <T> T get(Class<? extends T> cls) {
        return injector.getInstance(cls);
    }

    public ApplicationContext() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module() {
            binder.bind(InterfaceOne.class).to(ImplementationOne.class);
            binder.bind(InterfaceTwo.class).to(ImplementationTwo.class);
            binder.bind(InterfaceThree.class).to(ImplementationThree.class);
        });
    }
}
```

}

where `ImplementationThree` depends on `InterfaceTwo`, and `ImplementationTwo` in turn depends on `InterfaceOne`.

What I want now, is that after `ImplementationTwo` is instantiated, I want to wrap it in a Proxy before it's injected into `ImplementationThree`. So:

- I want to use Guice to have `ImplementationOne` being injected into `ImplementationTwo`
- Before `ImplementationTwo` is injected into `ImplementationThree`, I want to wrap it.

What I'd love to see, is a Guice interceptor that is invoked after the instantiation and injection of dependencies, but before it's handed over to the injector context.

I could use a `Provider` for `ImplementationTwo`, but then I don't know how to get an instance of `InterfaceOne` from Guice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Provider method can also use injection. Try

```
@Inject @Provides
public InterfaceTwo provideInterfaceTwo(InterfaceOne i){
    return InterfaceTwoImplementation
}
```

Comment: Note that instances created manually do not participate in AOP, i. e. you can't use method interceptors with them. It's rarely a restriction, but it can be sometimes.

Comment: And what if you want to wrap what you have into a proxy and return it under the same interface?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use plain old Guice AOP support? Something like

```
@SynchronizedAccess
public void foo(...){
    ...
}
```

this way you can see just by looking at the code that there is something more to the method.

If you absolutely want to wrap things in a Proxy:

If you only have a few classes to proxy, then @acerberus suggestions works fine.

To automate, you can use a [#afterInjection](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/InjectionListener.html), part of [Custom Injections](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections), and reassign the field to your proxy using reflection.

I find it a bit archaic to program using locks while we have things like [akka](http://akka.io) around but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for providing two solutions outside what was asked (and what my customer could live with).`#afterInjection` would certainly be achievable, but ugly IMHO.